# Заменить дефолтный HTML тэг VUE компонентом

Tags: vue.js

Мне нужно, чтобы глобально, на всём сайте, тэг `h1` заменялся кастомным компонентом. Однако такой код не даёт результата:

```js
Vue.component('h1', {
  template: '<div>REPLACED</div>'
})
new Vue({ el: 'vue' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<vue>
  <h1>
    lalalala
  </h1>
</vue>
```

Как добиться нужного мне результата?

Comment: Зачем тебе это нужно?

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович _чтобы глобально, на всём сайте, тэг h1 заменялся кастомным компонентом_